# xp_md5.dll for 64-bit

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am right now using this extended stored procedure in one of the test database on sql server 2008 and it works fine. I tried to do the same on a different sql server and it did not work on that. Then I got an explaination that the former was a 32 bit processor and latter was a 64 bit processor. Is there anyway to make use of this extended stored procedure on a 64-bit processor!!!

I need recompile version of xp_md5.dll for 64-bit.

Thanks in advance

Comment: consider switching to SHA2, MD5 has been broken.

Comment: Alex's hashbytes sounds the simplest way forward. You haven't told us what problems you're having porting / recompiling though. Is this the code you're using? http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/xp_md5.aspx

Comment: I don't know how to recompile the dll with 64-bit. can anyone tell me the procedure how can i do that?

Comment: You'd have to fetch the source from CodeProject, open it up in Visual Studio with a 64-bit compiler installed, add a new target or modify the existing targets to be 64-bit, skim through the code for assumptions that ints / pointers are 32-bit, turn up the warning level, compile, solve all the warnings and test. Then it'd probably be worth contributing the 64-bit build / modified source back to CodeProject because lots of people seem to want it.

Comment: thanks for that. i will do that right now and put it on codeproject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an MD5 why not use 2008's built in `HASHBYTES()`?

```
DECLARE @IN  NVARCHAR(4000) = N'Hello'
DECLARE @OUT VARBINARY(16)

SET @OUT = HASHBYTES('MD5', @IN)

SELECT @OUT
```

Comment: hi alex,

i can not use hashbytes because we are migrating the database from 32-bit to 64-bit.

Comment: I don't follow - why does that stop you using the hashbytes function? It ought to be a drop-in replacement for `xp_md5`. If you're using `xp_md5x` you might need to do a bit of work cutting up the string, though.

Comment: This function was producing a different hash for me initially. This is what I ended up using to give the same results as fn_md5: substring(master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr(HASHBYTES('MD5', cast(@password as varchar(50)))), 3, 32)